# Class does not implement interface member - but the method is already included in the class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class and an interface with currently only one method. Even though the method is implemented, I am still getting this error:

> 'PaymentManifestController' does not implement interface member 'IPaymentManifestController.CreateNewPaymentManifest(PaymentInstruction)'

I am not sure why - as I have already implemented the method.

PaymentManifestController.cs:

```
public class PaymentManifestController : IPaymentManifestController
{
    public IAction CreateNewPaymentManifest(PaymentInstruction request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

IPaymentManifestController.cs:

```
public interface IPaymentManifestController
{
    IAction CreateNewPaymentManifest(PaymentInstruction request);
}
```

`PaymentInstruction` is an object which defines several parameters, while `IAction` is an external library we use - both projects the files are in are referencing the `Actions` library. The concrete class' project also references the interfaces project.

Adding additional properties and methods such as `void foo()` to the interface and implementing them in the class works - it is just this method which doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can make it work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only cause I can imagine is that the two files refer to either `IAction` or `PaymentInstruction` in a different scope, so they're not the same type and therefore the method signatures don't match. Double check that you don't have any duplicates of those types being referenced by your project.

Comment: Are there multiple implementations of  `PaymentInstruction` in different namespaces?

Comment: @TomW I have just checked - there aren't any. There is only one class named PaymentInstruction, it does however inherit from its own interface no problem.

Comment: @ScottHannen No - All of the interfaces and classes are sharing the same namespace.

Comment: The interface need to be outside a class so all code in different classes can access the object.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution - Instead of using the class type as a parameter in the method - I used its interface. This has made the error go away. Not sure why it appeared in the first place however, it seemed perfectly logical.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution - one for me anyway, posting in case other people come across the same issue.

Instead of using the class type as a parameter in the method - I used its interface. I changed this in both the interface and the class. This fixed the error.

```
public class PaymentManifestController : IPaymentManifestController
{
    // Notice I have changed PaymentInstruction to IPaymentInstruction.
    public IAction CreateNewPaymentManifest(IPaymentInstruction request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```